# Exclude .InstallState file from MSI

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation

I'm using `Installer Class` in my MSI project which preforms some custom actions. Due to this class everytime I install the MSI it places `.InstallState` file into installation folder. I have another module in my project which performs uninstallation of existing application in `Silent mode` using existing application's product code. But its failing as it couldnt remove the .InstallState file. But if i manually uninstall it removes the file.

After installing the app i tried to delete this file within `OnCommit()` or `Commit()` methods of installer class using `File.Delete()`. But so far no luck.

Is there any way to exclude this file from MSI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this, During installation i'm doing a `File.Delete()`. I'm deleteing the file within `OnComitting()` of installer class.

```
protected override void OnCommitting(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
{
    string installedPath = string.Empty;
    installedPath = Context.Parameters["assemblypath"];
    installedPath = installedPath.Substring(0, installedPath.LastIndexOf('\\'));

    File.Delete(Path.Combine(installedPath, "InstallerHelper.InstallState"));

    base.OnCommitting(savedState);

}
```